# Can't move large files, always get Input/output error after some time

Tags: mac-osx, hard-drive, mv

I want to move a large file (hdd of a paralells vm, 81G) from one hd to another. After some time I get the error message: Input/output error. What can I do to move the file?

I checked source and target drive (with the osx internal tools), they reported no error. I also tries to copy the file to another hdd connected via USB, same problem.

Comment: You could try (1) running Disk Utility to check whether your disk is doing fine, (2) checking your system logs to see if anything of interest is logged right after you get the `Input/output error`. Perhaps you can also use `sudo dmesg|tail` and look at its output, just to be sure you aren't missing anything useful.

Comment: Are you sure you're not running out of space on the target drive?

Comment: yes there is enough space.

Comment: How are you copying the file? Ui, commandline?

Answer (score 2):

I'd first suggest that you find out the problem with the disk and correct it before attempting the copy again.  When you get the input/output error, that usually means that your disk has a hardware problem.